# K8S Cert-manager wont add DNS01 RFC2136 Challenge for a primary zone in a less privilege sub zone (DNS REFUSED)

Tags: bind, kubernetes

Apologies ahead, this is likely to be a misunderstanding on my part, but for the life of me I can not see the reasons why cert-manager is trying to write to the primary zone and not the subzone per instructions

[Delegated Zones in Cert-manager](https://cert-manager.io/docs/configuration/acme/dns01/#delegated-domains-for-dns01).

My current thought is that cert-manager is ignoring the CNAME and trying to write direct to the primary zone

Whats not working

- cert-manager creating a cert for test.example.org in test.acme.example.org

Whats working

- DNS queries to both example.org and acme.example.org
- Adding records via `nsupdate -k updates.key` to acme.example.org
- cert-manager creating a cert for test.acme.example.org

Whats checked

- Confirm that cert-manager is utilising the correct "internal" view etc so have only shown those items

Note updates.key is a key via `tsig-keygen updates.key > updates.key`

**Bind9 - Named.conf.local**

```
view "internal" {
  #Global View Settings
  match-clients { !testingip; internals; };
  recursion yes;
  allow-query { any; };

  #Internal for our Primary Zone  
  zone "example.org." IN {
    type primary;
    file "zones/int/db.example.org";
    allow-transfer { key ns1-ns2.key; };
    notify explicit;
    also-notify { 10.8.23.74; };
    check-names warn;
    #update-policy { grant updates.key subdomain acme.example.org any; };
    allow-update { none; };
  };

  #For LetsEncrypt
  zone "acme.example.org." IN {
    type primary;
    file "zones/common/db.acme.example.org";
    allow-update { key updates.key; };
    allow-transfer { key ns1-ns2.key; };
    notify explicit;
    also-notify { 10.8.23.74; };
    allow-query { any; };
  };
};
```

**/etc/bind/zones/int/db.example.org**

```
$ORIGIN example.org.
$TTL 86400      ; 1 day
@                       IN SOA  ns1.example.org. admin.example.org. (
                                64         ; serial
                                43200      ; refresh (12 hours)
                                7200       ; retry (2 hours)
                                1209600    ; expire (2 weeks)
                                43200      ; minimum (12 hours)
                                )
                        NS      ns1.example.org.
                        NS      ns2.example.org.
_acme-challenge      IN  CNAME   _acme-challenge.acme.example.org.
_acme-challenge.www  IN  CNAME   _acme-challenge.acme.example.org.
acme                    NS      ns1.example.org.
ns1                     A       10.8.23.73
ns2                     A       10.8.23.74
test                    A       10.8.23.71
```

**/etc/zones/common/db.acme.example.org**

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 86400      ; 1 day
acme.example.uk         IN SOA  ns1.example.org. admin.example.org. (
                                89         ; serial
                                43200      ; refresh (12 hours)
                                7200       ; retry (2 hours)
                                1209600    ; expire (2 weeks)
                                43200      ; minimum (12 hours)
                                )
                        NS      ns1.example.org
                        NS      ns2.example.org
$ORIGIN acme.example.org
test                    A       8.8.8.8
test2                   CNAME   test
test5                   A       1.1.1.1
```

**Kubernetes Configs**

```
#Issuer
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: example.org-issuer
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  acme:
    email: james@example.org
    server: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: exampleorg-issuer-account-key
    solvers:
    - dns01:
        cnameStrategy: Follow
        rfc2136:
          nameserver: 10.8.23.73
          tsigKeyName: updates.key
          tsigAlgorithm: HMACSHA256
          tsigSecretSecretRef:
            name: dns-updates-key
            key: tsig-secret-key
      selector:
        dnsZones:
        - 'example.org'
        
#Certificate that wont work       
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: www-example-org
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  secretName: www-example-org-tls
  issuerRef:
    name: example.org-issuer
    kind: Issuer
  commonName: 'www.example.org'
  dnsNames:
    - 'www.example.org'
    
#Certificate that works
microk8s kubectl apply -f - << EOF
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Certificate
metadata:
  name: acme-example-org
  namespace: cert-manager
spec:
  secretName: acme-example-org-tls
  issuerRef:
    name: example.org-issuer
    kind: Issuer
  commonName: 'www.acme.example.org'
  dnsNames:
    - 'www.acme.example.org'
EOF
```

**Errors**

```
#Kubernetes Error
controller.go:167] cert-manager/challenges "msg"="re-queuing item due to error processing" "error"="DNS update failed. Server replied: REFUSED" "key"="cert-manager/www-example-org-zwrzv-1914768330-2709226250"

#Bind Confirm
24-Mar-2023 18:14:15.232 client @0x7f38b0002108 10.1.76.188#38695: view internal: using view 'internal'
24-Mar-2023 18:14:15.232 client @0x7f38b0002108 10.1.76.188#38695: view internal: request has valid signature: updates.key
24-Mar-2023 18:14:15.232 client @0x7f38b0002108 10.1.76.188#38695/key updates.key: view internal: recursion available
24-Mar-2023 18:14:15.232 client @0x7f38b0002108 10.1.76.188#38695/key updates.key: view internal: updating zone 'example.org/IN': prerequisites are OK
24-Mar-2023 18:14:15.232 client @0x7f38b0002108 10.1.76.188#38695/key updates.key: view internal: set ede: info-code 18 extra-text (null)
24-Mar-2023 18:14:15.232 client @0x7f38b0002108 10.1.76.188#38695/key updates.key: view internal: signer "updates.key" denied
24-Mar-2023 18:14:15.232 client @0x7f38b0002108 10.1.76.188#38695/key updates.key: view internal: update 'example.org/IN' denied
24-Mar-2023 18:14:15.232 client @0x7f38b0002108 10.1.76.188#38695/key updates.key: view internal: updating zone 'example.org/IN': rolling back
24-Mar-2023 18:14:15.232 client @0x7f38b0002108 10.1.76.188#38695/key updates.key: view internal: reset client
```

**Versions**
Bind 9.18
cert-manager 1.11.0

Answer (score 0):

I walked away, came back 16 hours later and there was a certificate sat there.....